# Regex text in between identical markers

Tags: regex

I have a document of the form:

```
*##:##* text
*##:##* more text
and here is some more
*##:##* even more text
```

where the # is any number

I'm trying to write a regex to find

```
*##:##* text
```

and

```
*##:##* more text
and here is some more
```

and

```
*##:##* even more text
```

My current regex looks like:

```
'\*([0-9][0-9]:[0-9][0-9])\*(.+?)(?=(\*([0-9][0-9]:[0-9][0-9])\*|\Z))'
```

however it generates spurious results of just the number format and some of the text. What would the correct regex look like?

Comment: Unrelated: You could turn `[0-9][0-9]` into `\d{2}`. Much easier to follow and read.

Comment: Regexes can be partial to the language you are using...so, which lang?

Comment: `\*` in this, the \ is escaping the `*` to make it literal. You should have `\\\*` there to match `\*`.

Comment: the regular expression will go into a cocoa app to import data and cocoa follows the ICU standard

Comment: ah the \* were my error, they are just * will edit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The key thing is that you have to explicitly add the new line character if you want your regex to be able to match content dispatched over multiple lines.

```
\*\d\d:\d\d\*((.|\n)(?!(\*\d\d:\d\d\*)))*
```